# Recursive function that calls itself n times without using n as a parameter

Tags: php, language-agnostic, loops, recursion

Suppose I have myFunction($var).  It will manipulate $var, calling itself 3 times before finally returning $var.  Is there a way to do this without storing the number of times it's been called in the parameters?

Comment: why is this tagged both php and language-agnostic ???

Comment: Perhaps if whatever `$var` is causes the function to recurse exactly 3 times.

Comment: Carlos -- because there might be a shortcut in php, but this could be helped by those who know any language.  BoltClock- nope, $var has no relation to the # of times, its just an array thats being manipulated with no reference to that

Comment: Why can't you pass the number of times it has been called in the parameters?  That would be the 'right' way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two competing methods off the top of my head:

1. static global data
2. transform $var in such a way that you can detect how many times it's been manipulated

Comment: Based on the comments above it looks like these tricks are the only way.  Going to accept as an answer if there's no natural way to do this

Comment: "natural way"?!!  The mind boggles!  Do you know of *any* language which has a "natural way" of doing this?

Comment: wallyk- i'm a beginning programmer, so i don't know recursion patterns very well

Comment: There is a natural way, pass n as a parameter :D

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this is to make the `n` optional and defaults to 3 if not defined. I don't know the PHP syntax for this but since it's tagged language agnostic here's the javascript equivalent:

```
function myFunction (var, n) {
    if (n == undefined) {
        n = 3;
    }

    doSomethingWith(var);

    n--;

    if (n) {
        myFunction(var, n);
    }
}

// called like this:
myFunction(someVar);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the recursive portion of that read `if (n > 0) { myFunction( var n ); }` ?

Comment: @Armstrongest: I don't expect `n` to be less than 0. But yes, from a defensive programming perspective checking `n>0` is safer than checking if `n` is zero (false)

Comment: Yep, I get it... I just have always found it disconcerting relying on !0 = true. Must be all the time I spent with languages that have strong types like `C#` and `Java`. It just seems to be better to be explicit in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the static statement to set a var and check its value each time you go in (incrementing it each time, of course, as you enter, decrementing as you exit).
Here's an article on the basic concept.
http://www.bellaonline.com/articles/art29070.asp

The relevant code is

```
 function count_calls( )
{
static $no_calls = 0;
$no_calls++;
echo "This function has been called $no_calls times.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what happens *after* the recursive calls, so…

`setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK)` to a small value and/or consume enough stack space in other calls that `myFunction()` can only recurse 3 times before aborting due to lack of stack space.

Answer (score 0):

Some functional languages support this kind of construct.

In Mathematica, for example you may define:

```
     f[i_, n_: 3] := Nest[# + 7 &, i, n];
```

Where 3 is a default value for n.

So

```
     f[2]
```

Returns

```
     23  -> (2+7+7+7)
```

and

```
     f[4,1]
```

Returns

```
     11 (-> 4+7)
```

Of course you may also define

```
     f[i_] := Nest[# + 7 &, i, 3];
```

if you don't need to adjust the number of recursive calls.

---

Perhaps this is more interesting. You may ask also for all the intermediate results.

So, if you define:

```
g[i_, n_: 3] := NestList[# + 7 &, i, n];
```

then

```
g[2] Returns {2, 9, 16, 23}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your function will call itself exacly three times, four with the time *you* called it, it is better to make a simpler, non-recursive function and make the calling explicit:

`simpleF(simpleF(simpleF(simpleF($var))))`

Less elegant, but more maintenable.

Of course, this wouldn't scale for a bigger number.